# Does apocalyptic Judaism still exist?

Tags: non-rabbinic-judaism

In studying the history of Christianity, and therefore, the historical context of the early Jesus Movement, which was obviously a Jewish context, I have been led to understand that in the first century, there was a popular form of Judaism now referred to as apocalyptic, or eschatological, Judaism.

Generally speaking, eschatological Jews believed the following:

- The universe was a sort of cosmic battleground, and the forces of darkness, death, sin, and wickedness were doing battle with the forces of light, life, virtue, and righteousness.
- God was still in control of this world in some ultimate sense. But for unknown and mysterious reasons he had temporarily relinquished his control to the forces of evil that opposed him.
- This state of affairs would not go on forever.  Soon - **very** soon - G-d would intervene directly.
- He would soon send his emissary, occasionally referred to as the "Son of Man", but more often as the messiah.
- The messiah  would arrive in the world and usher in the Kingdom of G-d;  he would then sit in judgment over mankind, both living and dead;  the wicked would be laid low, and the righteous would be richly rewarded for their piety.
- The Kingdom would be established, with its capital in Jerusalem, and Israel would take her place as the greatest of all nations.
- The forces of darkness, death, sin, and wickedness would be crushed once and for all.

For a more comprehensive definition of apocalyptic Judaism, see the document linked [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-4Hr-3EoYjIZ0lzgUfpjOexMpReh5ULyH3FP0A6ENPU/edit?usp=docslist_api) or [here](http://justpaste.it/n2pd)

At long last, we come to the point of all of this:

**Does apocalyptic Judaism still exist today?**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what some of your terms mean (like "Son of Man"), but I'm not so sure that your claim that this isn't the mainstream belief in Judaism is true. If your definition of apocalyptic is "the world was approaching a drastic turning point. Wickedness and sin had grown to dominate much of the world's population, and soon, G-d would intervene directly," I think something similar to that is a mainstream opinion of modern Judaism.

Comment: By the way, there are Jews today who actively search for red heifers. I'm not exactly sure why Christians would be looking for one unless they are planning on restarting the Temple service; but Jews want to have one in case the Messiah comes and rebuilds the Holy Temple in Jerusalem. Then we would need the red heifer to purify ourselves.

Comment: If I understand your description in the question correctly, then I think you can say mainstream (or orthodox or traditional) Judaism is apocalyptic. We believe that people are constantly fighting to do right against the pull of their baser selves that urges them to do wrong, and that a time will come when what's good and bad will be apparent. Or thereabouts. I'm not sure that's what you meant through. And I'm not sure where to source the answer from, so am not posting it as one (yet).

Comment: @WadCheber, I'm not sure why. The more comprehensive a description you give, the less likely (that anyone will read it and) that any Jews today believe in it. If you want to know whether any Jews today believe precisely the same thing that some specific non-mainstream group believed millennia ago, then your answer is probably "no" -- but of course you're welcome to ask, and the Google Doc may help. If, otoh, you mean to ask about specific core beliefs of that old group, then I suggest you pare your question down to them, and the Google Doc probably is unnecessary in that case.

Comment: @msh210 - Regarding your first comment, I think the difference between what you describe and apocalyptic Judaism is that the latter attributes the existence of sin and suffering not to the inherent fallibility of humanity, but to the cosmic forces of evil.

Comment: @WadCheber There are undoubtedly going to be some differences between _any_ Jewish sect of the first century and _any_ Jewish sect of today. It's not clear exactly to what extent you want to match up the group from then to a group from now, so I am voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: So, did these "apocalyptic Jews" have any writings? Any famous rabbis? I've just never heard of such a thing, especially the idea that "G-d has abandoned the world" ([Ezekiel 9:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16107#v=9)) to the forces of evil, which is just about as antithetical a belief to Judaism as they come.

Comment: @HodofHod Yes these apocalyptic Jews left lots of writings. Some of which are extant in the dead sea scrolls, talking about the end of days, for which people wouldn't have sex or have kids for fear that they wold be impure when God would come to destroy the world.

Comment: @HodofHod - The Dead Sea Scrolls, the books of Daniel and 1 Enoch, and most of the Christian bible are examples of apocalyptic texts.  In fact, there is an entire genre of apocalyptic texts.

Comment: @WadCheber "But for unknown and mysterious reasons he had temporarily relinquished his control to the forces of evil that opposed him." Sorry, but this is a Christian idea. In Judaism, G-d wants the "evil" to test us, and then we'd be deserving of reward or as punishment. But the evil does not oppose him.

Comment: @Aaron honestly? The dead Sea scrolls is a very unreliable sources. We don't know who wrote it, we know it's full of mistakes, even if the chumash, compared to more reliable texts.

Comment: @WadCheber in the document: The forces of good were headed by God himself, the forces of evil by his superhuman enemy, sometimes called Satan, or Beelzebub, or the Devil... This idea is 100% from Christianity

Comment: @user613, no, it is 100% the basis for Christianity, which grew from preexisting Jewish traditions.

Comment: @WadCheber Christianity is not fully based on Judaism, and this part isn't. Quote me one reliable Jewish source. Not a whole book that I'll have to go through, but more specific.

Comment: @user613 Saying that the dead sea scrolls are unreliable because their Chumash is different than ours doesn't prove they are unreliable, all it says is that someone's text is unreliable, and it could be ours. Why could it be ours? Because many of the dead sea scrolls also reflect what we know and find in the Septuagint. Things we thought were bad Greek translations turned out to have valid Hebrew sources.

Comment: @user613 - *Wisdom of Solomon* is a good place to start, bearing in mind that the point isn't about whether this belief system was orthodox, only whether it existed.

Comment: @WadCheber I just Google searched it. It's a Christian book that some claim to be from Solomon. I asked for Jewish texts. Unless you mean Wisdom of Solomon from the maharshal, in which case, it doesn't support you at all.

Comment: @user613 please explain how a Christian book could have been written as much as 220 years before Jesus was born.

Comment: http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/wisdom.html

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14951-wisdom-of-solomon-book-of-the

Comment: @WadCheber I mean that is recognised asking Christianity, and some Christians added it to the bible. This isn't a reliable Jewish source

Comment: @user613 - I'm going to step out of this conversation because you don't seem to understand the fact that a source's reliability is independent of your approval of the theology and cosmology it contains.

Comment: @WadCheber I don't even know what it contains. If I look, I can find you a million books on Christianity, but Christians will say that it's not a Christian thing. Around 500 years ago, there were a lot of Christian beliefs based on Greek texts, from the likes of Aristotle. Just because there's a book that may have been written by an Egyptian Jew 2000 years ago, doesn't mean that it's reliable.

Comment: @user613 It (presumably) reliably records the theology of its author. That's all that matters here. Not if that theology accords with your theology. You don't seem to understand this question at all. Nothing you've said has been constructive.

Comment: @DoubleAA Jews have been monotheistic since the inception of Judaism. If you have some heretic who holds that "the devil" has power to fight against G-d, well, that's polytheistic and isn't Judaism.

Comment: @user613 You are right that it certainly would not be Rabbinic Judaism. If only we had a tag for such questions... (Please try and read the whole question in the future before wasting our time in the comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, apocalyptic Judaism no longer exists. Sects like those at Qumran no longer exist, and no one is writing in the apocalyptic style (books of Daniel, Enoch, Revelations, and many of the scrolls of Qumran). We can debate all day long as to why. Maybe Jews were tired of predicting the end, but the end never came. Maybe the entire consensus shifted on what we should be focusing on? Maybe after x-amount of false messiahs we're just jaded? Who knows.

But the scholarly discussion of apocalyptic Judaism no longer seems to exist.